# htaccess URL wrong redirection

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect

- `/about`
- `/about/`
- `/about.html`
- `/about.html/`
- `/weare/`
- `/weare`
- `/weare.html`
- `/weare.html/`

All these pages should be redirected to `about.html` and I want to do this with .htaccess.

I wast trying by

```
RewriteRule ^(about|weare).*/ about.html [R=Permanent]
```

This is somewhat working, but not exactly what I want. It is also redirecting some other pages.

I have added as said by ThinkingMonkey

If you want to do a permanent redirect:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about\.html$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(about|weare)(\.html)?/?$ about.html [L,R=301]
```

This is working But it is going for infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
RewriteRule ^(about|weare)(/|\.html/?)?$ about.html [L]
```

If you want to do a permanent redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(about|weare)(\.html)?/?$ about.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: the second one is not working. it  is going for infinite loop..i think it is redirecting .html too

Comment: @Midars Well this is embarrassing! Too many over sights. Check the update.

Comment: @Midars I just tested it here. Am not getting any redirection loops. Do you have any other rewriterules in the same file? I have just optimised the last line a bit.

Comment: i have but not related to this condition...i will check this one..thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule ^((about|weare)(.|/)?(html)?) about.html [NC]`

Comment: this is giving 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: sorry, you're right. I edited it. btw: for testing there are two awesome tools: [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) and [rewriteRule Tester](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/)

Comment: thanks but this [NC] does not work how i want this to work. if i add [L,R=301] it goes for infinite loop